# Vault Transit migrate to another server

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have a Vault server with Transit engine enabled, now I want to migrate the server to another location/hosting,
Ho do I export/import existing keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can first migrate seal from transit to shamir. ( Your Recovery Keys Will be your unseal keys ). Then migrate seal to transit ( your second server ). This is only way and at a time of migrating to shamir your first server must be up and ruuning.